# Force client disconnect using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to force clients to disconnect from PostgreSQL? I'm looking for the equivlent of DB2's [`force application all`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0001951.htm).

I'd like to do this on my development box because when I've got database consoles open, I can't load a database dump. I have to quit them first.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Combine [`pg_terminate_backend`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE) function and the [`pg_stat_activity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS) system view.

Comment: pg_cancel_backend() doesn't disconnect, it only cancels the current query. Next query can come in any second using the same old connection that is still there.

Answer (score 39):

Kills idle processes in PostgreSQL 8.4:

```
SELECT procpid, (SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid)) as killed from pg_stat_activity
   WHERE current_query LIKE '<IDLE>';
```

Comment: Works like a charm in Postgres v9.1.4. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: On latest postgres versions: `SELECT pid, (SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)) as killed from pg_stat_activity WHERE state LIKE 'idle';`

Comment: This works... except pgAdmin crashes when it tries to reconnect! Back to sqaure one :(

Answer (score 7):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3185413/2171120) beautifully explains (full quote from [araqnid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85134/araqnid) between the horizontal rules, then me again):

---

To mark database 'applogs' as not accepting new connections:

```
update pg_database set datallowconn = false where datname = 'applogs';
```

Another possibility would be to revoke 'connect' access on the database for the client role(s).

Disconnect users from database = kill backend. So to disconnect all other users from "applogs" database, for example:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'applogs' and procpid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Once you've done both of those, you are the only user connected to 'applogs'. Although there might actually be a delay before the backends actually finish disconnecting?

---

Update from [MarkJL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1010873/markjl): There is indeed a delay before the backends finish disconnecting.

Now me again: That being said, mind that the `procpid` column was renamed to `pid` in PostgreSQL 9.2 and later.

I think that this is much more helpful than the answer by Milen A. Radev which, while technically the same, does not come with usage examples and real-life suggestions.

Comment: There is definitely a delay in backend disconnections.

Answer (score 4):

I post my answer because I couldn't use any of them in my script, server 9.3:

```
psql -U postgres -c "SELECT pid, (SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)) as killed from pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'my_database_to_alter';"
```

In the next line, you can do anything yo want with 'my_database_to_alter'. As you can see, yo perform the query from the "postgres" database, which exists almost in every postgresql installation.

Doing by superuser and outside the problem-database itself worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

probably a more heavy handed approach then should be used but:

```
for x in `ps -eF | grep -E "postgres.*idle"| awk '{print $2}'`;do kill $x; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread](http://archives.postgresql.org//pgsql-admin/2008-09/msg00224.php) on the mailing list. It suggests using SIGTERM to cause the clients to disconnect.

Not as clean as `db2 force application all`.