# PostgreSQL: Temporarily disable connections

Tags: postgresql

I have a script in PostgreSQL which restores test database from dump every night. The database is accessed by app servers and processes with connection pool which keeps a few connections alive at all times.

So the script restores dump into `my_temp_database`. Then it should rename `my_database` to `my_old_database`, `my_temp_database` to `my_database`, and eventually drop `my_old_database`.

How can I disconnect all clients, superuser or not, from `my_database`, so that it can be renamed? How I can I temporarily prevent them from reconnecting?

Is there a better way to do what I need?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To mark database 'applogs' as not accepting new connections:

```
update pg_database set datallowconn = false where datname = 'applogs';
```

Another possibility would be to revoke 'connect' access on the database for the client role(s).

Disconnect users from database = kill backend. So to disconnect all other users from "applogs" database, for example:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'applogs' and procpid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Once you've done both of those, you are the only user connected to 'applogs'. Although there might actually be a delay before the backends actually finish disconnecting?

Comment: In 8.3 you can try `select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity;`

Comment: @araqnid The comand "update pg_database set datallowconn = false where datname = 'applogs';" works like a charm! "REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE" does not work for me! UP! UP! UP! UP! UP! UP!

Answer (score 18):

After you have terminated the current active connections you can also issue this command that will only allow super users to login.  This assumes you are ok with all super users having access still. Hopefully you don't hand out super user rights to just anyone.

```
ALTER DATABASE your_db CONNECTION LIMIT 0;
```

Answer (score 18):

Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 we finally can:

```
ALTER DATABASE db WITH ALLOW_CONNECTIONS false;
```

Comment: Tried using this, but it only works if the db in question is not the one you are connected to and if the user executing the command is the owner of the db (or su).

Comment: sounds logical though

Answer (score 3):

If you are connected in session with the DB that you want to dissallow connecting to, and to stay connected in the same session after you disallow connections, then use this :

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = false WHERE datname = '_db_name_' ;
```

... which allows you to do stuff without any other connection happening until you re-enable

But if you use this, it must be from in a session in another DB :

```
ALTER DATABASE _db_name_ WITH ALLOW_CONNECTIONS false ;
```

(( i realise this is almost a summary of the answers above ))

Answer (score 2):

I had a different usage scenario, in which I wanted to disable a DB for everyone (including superuser) and forever, but not plainly drop it just yet, to be able to reactivate it quickly if needed.

This worked fine on an old 8.3 Postgres:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn=false WHERE datname='my_db_name';
```