# How to clone a test database from a production one in one single action?

Tags: postgresql, templates, database-connection, postgresql-9.1

I am looking for a basic script/command that will create a copy of a live database (let name them `mydb` and `mydb_test`, both on the same server).

Requirements

- it has to run even if the `mydb_test` already exists and have records
- it has to work even if `mydb` and `mydb_test` do have existing connections
- it have to clean the potentially existing database if necessary

Hints:

- `drop database` cannot be used if you have existing connections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I was looking for, but I had to compile it myself :P

I only wish I knew a way to keep the same user and not having to put it inside the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_SRC=conf
DB_DST=conf_test
DB_OWNER=confuser

T="$(date +%s)"

psql -c "select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='$DB_DST';" || { echo "disconnect users failed"; exit 1; }
psql -c "drop database if exists $DB_DST;" || { echo "drop failed"; exit 1; }
psql -c "create database $DB_DST owner confuser;" || { echo "create failed"; exit 1; }
pg_dump $DB_SRC|psql $DB_DST || { echo "dump/restore failed"; exit 1; }

T="$(($(date +%s)-T))"
echo "Time in seconds: ${T}"
```

Answer (score 11):

The simplest and fastest method to create a complete copy of an existing (live) database is to use [`CREATE DATABASE` with a `TEMPLATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html):

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb_test TEMPLATE mydb;
```

However, there is an **important limitation** violating your second requirement: the template (source) database cannot have additional connections to it. [I quote the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)

> It is possible to create additional template databases, and indeed one
> can copy any database in a cluster by specifying its name as the
> template for `CREATE DATABASE`. It is important to understand, however,
> that this is not (yet) intended as a general-purpose "`COPY DATABASE`"
> facility. The principal limitation is that no other sessions can be
> connected to the source database while it is being copied. `CREATE DATABASE`
> will fail if any other connection exists when it starts; during
> the copy operation, new connections to the source database are prevented.

You can terminate all sessions to the template database if you have the necessary privileges with [`pg_terminate_backend()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE).
To temporarily disallow reconnects, [revoke the `CONNECT` privilege](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16426/how-to-drop-all-connections-to-a-specific-database-without-stopping-the-server/16427#comment25338_16427) (and `GRANT` back later).

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb FROM PUBLIC;

-- while connected to another DB - like the default maintenance DB "postgres"
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM   pg_stat_activity
WHERE  datname = 'mydb'                    -- name of prospective template db
AND    pid <> pg_backend_pid();            -- don't kill your own session

CREATE DATABASE mydb_test TEMPLATE mydb;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO PUBLIC;  -- only if they had it before
```

In versions *before* Postgres 9.2 use `procpid` instead of `pid`:

- [How to drop a PostgreSQL database if there are active connections to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408156/how-to-drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it/13245265#13245265)

Related:

- [Force drop db while others may be connected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11895/3684)

---

If you cannot afford to terminate concurrent sessions, go with piping the output of `pg_dump` to `psql` like has been suggested by other answers already.

Comment: I've beed trying to do this but the created DB is always empty. When I execute the code from the answer I get this as output `CREATE DATABASE`. Then I connect to the new DB and list the tables and I get `Did not find any relations.`. I would appreciate any guidance on what could be going wrong.

Comment: @MiguelFerreira: The method is tried and good. There must be some misunderstanding. Are you connected to the right DB? Are there any relations in the template? Consider a new question with details if you cannot solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't say it was a problem to drop *objects* in the database, I think running `pg_dump` with the `--clean` option will do what you want.  You can pipe the output of pg_dump into psql for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking into the [Hot Standby](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html) with [Streaming Replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION) here?

Comment: Hot Standby by definition is read only. so this only works if the test DB doesn't need to be written to