# Why do we need template0 and template1 in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm a beginner in PostgreSQL. I wonder why the `\l` command in psql shows databases `template0` and `template1`.

I searched the web but unfortunately didn't find the right resources. But I did find that after removing both (`template0` & `template1`) we can't create new databases any more.

Answer (score 60):

As the names indicate, those are template databases for creating new databases.

`template1` is the one used by default. You can alter / add / remove objects there to affect every newly created DB. [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html) basically makes a copy of it on the file level (very fast) to create a new instance.

`template0` starts out being the same and should never be changed - to provide a virgin template with original settings.

More details in the manual chapter ["Template Databases"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html).

But you can use any database of the same cluster as template with the  [`TEMPLATE` keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html) - as long as there are no open connections to it. This is useful to populate new databases quickly. See:

- [How to clone a test database from a production one in one single action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105489/how-to-clone-a-test-database-from-a-production-one-in-one-single-action/10107602#10107602)
- [Shell script to execute pgsql commands in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594717/shell-script-to-execute-pgsql-commands-in-files/8595568#8595568)
- [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database/12082038#12082038)