# sqlalchemy close all connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to drop my database using sqlalchemy:

```
def dropDb(self, dbName):
    self.closeConnection()
    self.selectDb(None)
    self.execute("drop database %s" % dbName)

def closeConnection(self):
    self._Session.close_all()
    self._engine.dispose()
    del self._Session
    del self._engine
```

I create the engine with:

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string, poolclass = NullPool)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Detail ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000]
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot drop database
> "test_db" because it is currently in use. (3702) (SQLExecDirectW)')
> 'drop database test_db' ()

How can I forcibly close ALL connections?

Comment: I believe the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5408156/377366) are what you need.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and what fixed my problem is adding the `session.close_all()` I saw in your question! That alongside `engine.dispose()` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

[The current method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=close_all_sessions#sqlalchemy.orm.session.close_all_sessions) for closing all connections using the SQLAlchemy sessions api is

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import close_all_sessions

close_all_sessions()
```

as `session.close_all()` is deprecated.

Comment: Technically, closing the sessions just checks the connections back into the pool.  You need to call `engine.dispose()` to close the connections - [Engine Disposal](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#engine-disposal).