# Check for connections before dropping DB

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I'm trying to drop a DB. Before dropping the DB I just want to check if there are any clients connected to that particular DB.

If No, I can drop it.

If Yes, I want to give the user some useful information.

I know this query, so I can see the number connections made to that DB.

`select count(*) from pg_stat_activity`

How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 2):

I would not bother checking `pg_stat_activity`, since even if you did, someone could access the database right afterward before you initiate the `DROP DATABASE` command.

Rather, I would recommend you just issue the `DROP DATABASE` command using whatever method you're using the interact with `Postgres` (`JDBC`, `MyBatis`, etc.) and surround it with a `try/catch` block. The `DROP DATABASE` command will fail if there are users connected to it, so you can simply execute the command and then handle the exception -- perhaps sleep for a few seconds and try again, or something to that effect.

However, if you wanted to **force** any active users off of the database, `pg_stat_activity` would come into play and you could terminate their backend connections, as outlined here: [How to drop a PostgreSQL database if there are active connections to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408156/how-to-drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it) and then issue the `DROP DATABASE` command.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

Like I said, since the `DROP` command would fail if there are connections to the DB, I wouldn't bother checking first, but if you really want to see what the connections are (except for the connection you're using the check), you can use a similar query to what was in the link above, just with the `pg_terminate_backend` call.

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'TARGET_DB'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Comment: Ken, whatever the link you shared is dealing with the closing active connections.I want to know , what are all the clients connected to that DB. Can you please reply?

Comment: added response to answer