# Drop database, postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nginx

I am trying to drop my production postgresql database but apparently, there are some processes that stop me. I host in DigitalOcean on Ubuntu 14.04 with nginx and puma.

The code I try in the console:

> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails db:drop
>   DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1

The error I get:

```
PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "****_production" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 5 other sessions using the database.
/home/deploy/sites/***/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
```

Any idea how to stop all processes and reset the database?

Comment: You need to terminate backned :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408156/how-to-drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it/5408501#5408501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your puma is still running which is using postgresql connection. 
Trying again after stopping all the process that might use your database connection. Also close any rails console that you would have open on server.

```
ps -aef | grep puma
```

This will give you the list of puma process that is running on server. You can get process id(PID) from there and use below to kill the process.

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Dont forget the replace PID with actual process id. Once you stopped all the processes that might using postgresql, you are good to go.

If are still not able to drop db and also not able to recall what might be using your database. Try forcefully dropping your database. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected) how to drop database forcefully.

Comment: Yep, that changed the error to "There are 4 other processes". However, the first command does not show any other processes

Answer (score 0):

You would need to shut down all processes that might be using your database. In your case it's most probably Puma, which you could stop by running `pumactl stop`.

If you still can't delete your DB, there might be other processes left there so have a look at the output of `ps aux` for anything that could still hold a connection (e.g. if you're using Sidekiq, Elasticsearch, etc). You can then terminate these by issuing a `kill` command with their process IDs.