# disconnecting pgadmin's connection via bash

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, connection

after registering the user in the postgres database(in ubuntu) we can execute some basic command like `dropdb`, `createdb` directly from the terminal to alter the database.

I basically was creating a shell script to renew the database. So, I thought doing this would suffice:

```
dropdb veganary_test && createdb veganary_test
```

as always, I was wrong. Since I had multiple connections to the database, db wouldn't drop. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408156/how-to-drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it):

```
    psql <database_name> -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
              FROM pg_stat_activity
              WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '<database_name>'
              AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();"
```

and, yet it wasn't successful on disrupting pgadmin's connection. How can I disconnect every user connected to my <database_name> database from the terminal?(bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to PostgreSQL v13 and use

```sh
dropdb --force veganary_test
```

Comment: the commands like `dropdb`, `createdb` , that can be executed directly from bash, does postgres have a specific term for them? or an exhaustive list of them somewhere?

Comment: They are called [PostgreSQL client applications](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/reference-client.html).

Comment: which this actually drops the table, I don't know if postgres maintains something like a stale reference, after dropping, and immediately setting up relations, I get issues, until I disconnect the database completely and then execute the command. Thats weird. Do you know how to force disconnect all users from  all available databases?

Comment: I basically just disconnected from localServer and then the command works