# Restoring a text `pg_dump` leaves a dangling session

Tags: postgresql

I dump a postgresql database on one machine as follows:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
pg_dump ire --clean --create --format=p > xfer.sql
```

On a second, private machine, whose database is not exposed to the network, I restore the dump with:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql -U postgres < xfer.sql
```

This works once, but then any attempt to overwrite the database gets this error message:

```
ERROR:  database "ire" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

I can easily fix it using e.g. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5408501/43839) but how can I avoid creating this dangling session in the first place?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when your consume the dump using `-f` (`--file`) flag? Eg.: `psql -U postgres -f xfer.sql`

Comment: Unfortunately, yes it does.

Comment: look in pg_stat_activity to see where the session is coming from.  Then use that knowledge to fix it.

Comment: It must be some session other than the `psql` session that restored the dump.

Comment: I just spun up this machine a few days ago.  No one else is using it for anything.  It's a very generic Ubuntu 20 with nothing installed.

I don't know how to "look in pg_stat_activity".  I don't see any such database or table.

Comment: I did install `pg_activity` and run it, going through all three query pages.  Everything seems empty...

Comment: It is a view with a full name of pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity.  It automatically exists in every database.