# Cannot drop a materialized view in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, materialized-views

I have a postgres db that runs on an AWS RDS instance. It contains a somewhat complicated materialized view (created by four left joins). I would like to drop it but the query never completes (no error message, it seems to hang). I am using Postico to execute my SQL queries.

I don't need this mv anymore, so I really only need to figure out how to drop it.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Kill all sessions with long running open transactions that used the MV.

Comment: I believe this was indeed it. An app that runs concurrent sessions had access to this view. Based on the code it accesses the mv only for short amounts of time but I think there were too many concurrent instances of this app that accessed the db. I restarted the app and then I was able to drop the mv.

@LaurenzAlbe if you post an explicit answer, I will mark it as "accepted"

Comment: Killing sessions is not a good practice. In my answer I recommend disabling new connections as well as trying to rename the view to be able to drop it later without issues.

Answer (score 0):

The system views [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) can tell you what's everyone doing, and [`pg_locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) who's holding what. You can once again re-experience your discomfort by

1. Setting the scenery in session A:

   ```
   create schema my_neighbourhood;
   select set_config('search_path','my_neighbourhood',false);
   create group family_that_owns_neighbourhood superuser inherit;
   alter schema my_neighbourhood owner to family_that_owns_neighbourhood;
   ```

   and introducing the princess

   ```
   create table good_values as select 'school' v1, 'hobbies' v2, 'sports' v3;
   create view daughter as select v1,v2,v3 from good_values;
   ```
2. Opening another session (B) in parallel and introducing the villain

   ```
   create user badboy420 
      in group family_that_owns_neighbourhood inherit superuser;
   start transaction;
   ```
3. The plot is rather predictible but you continue watching it unravel in session B's transaction:

   ```
   set role badboy420;
   select set_config('search_path','my_neighbourhood',true);
   insert into daughter values ('drugs','alcohol','tiktok');
   ```

   first one's enough to get her locked (up).
4. From session A, try to `drop view daughter;`, pretending this means you're casually trying to *drop daughter* ***off to school*** - it'll hang and you'll have to wait while she's still hanging out with that punk from session B. Luckily, until the situation's resolved, it would now also hang if someone tried to `alter view daughter rename to their_girlfriend;`, so, there's some silver lining.

You can insert a record scratching pause here.

The [post-mortem you shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77446465/cannot-drop-a-materialized-view-in-postgres#comment136534479_77446465) confirms that's pretty much what was going down. If you're very important, with little regard for whoever stands in your way, you can [`pg_cancel_backend()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#id-1.5.8.33.4.5.2.2.1.1.1.1)

```sql
select pg_cancel_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity 
where pid<>pg_backend_pid() and query ilike 'daughter';
```

If on top of being that important and ruthless, you're also in a big rush or [Liam Neeson](https://media.tenor.com/EPiQR_ycNX4AAAAd/i-will-find-you-iw-ill-eat-you.gif), you can go ahead and [`pg_terminate_backend()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#id-1.5.8.33.4.5.2.2.5.1.1.1) (you brute):

```sql
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity 
where pid<>pg_backend_pid() and query ilike 'daughter';
```

The first option is like finding the guy who's talking to your `daughter` and telling them to hang up. The second one is like finding them and ending the conversation by smacking them across the face hard enough that you break both their phone and potentially their jaw.

Note that in both cases above, you're actually doing that to anyone doing anything about any `daughter`, not just yours. But one: you get the point, two: that would actually send a good message.

If you want to be surgical about this, you can refer to [lock monitoring at PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring). Also, [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) can tell you *exactly* you who, since when, using what application, from what ip is trying to do what. With all that noted that down you easily track them down, can sue them into oblivion, get a restraining order, get their parole officer involved.

The default behaviour of putting you on hold and telling you to wait is actually a reasonable middle ground between strictness and good manners: it's waiting for everyone to finish what they had started doing, while already blocking newcomers. A third session trying to access would wait for the first one to complete, then the second one would be allowed to finish the drop, then the third one would be told `daughter` doesn't exist. Also, everyone involved can use all that wait time to cool off their temper.

Comment: It's intentionally [PEGI 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEGI#Age_ratings), but it'd be easy to fit a more PEGI 18 `insert` statement into the same analogy.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe there are running queries preventing to drop the object.

Try to rename it first.

ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW name
RENAME TO new_name

This way, new queries will fail.

Or try to disable new connections as explained here

[PostgreSQL: Temporarily disable connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185266/postgresql-temporarily-disable-connections?rq=4)

Comment: RENAME will also have to wait for a lock when other processes are still using this view. Both DROP and ALTER need a ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock

Comment: However, there can be other reasons, e.g. dropping the object also frees the allocated storage associated to it, so trying the rename can help in the diagnosis. I mentioned also to disable new connections in my answer.

Comment: You are right, there can be other reasons as well. But if you can rename the mat view, you could have dropped it as well: You need the same type of lock. Renaming doesn't add anything.