# Programmatically drop all connections

Tags: ruby, postgresql

At work, we do distributed testing, where rsync out to everyone elses machine and distribute out test files to speed up the testing process. One issue we are running into is that if someone has an instance of pgadmin open, it won't let us reset the test database due to connections being open.

Is there any way we can programmatically kill connections in either ruby or pg that doesn't involve restarting the daemon?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727194/force-client-disconnect-using-postgresql

Comment: @Milen: pg_cancel_backend() doesn't disconnect, it only cancels the current query. Next query can come in any second using the same old connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [pg_terminate_backend()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) to kill the connections you want to kill.